# How can I set up pinch zoom function and click to back to the last activity together?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I would like to set up a imageview onclicklistener that when user clicks the image, it back to the last activty. But somehow I need the pinch zoom function as well. The problem is, when I try to pinch and zoom, the listener thinks I'm clicking the image, so it backs to the last activity. How can I achieve both?

Comment: i am using this https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view library for pinch-zoom and image clicking is working perfect with it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to do both on the same time or one by one.
But here is one thought.

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Animation anim = null;
            // init your anim
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent());
                }
            });

            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

Start the intent after the whole anim is done.

Comment: No it doesn't work. The situation is: now I got a `ScaleImageView` class that was created by me, it contains event about how to zoom and drag the image. But in that `ScaleImageView` class it has a `onTouchListener`, in the listener every events are going to against me to click and `finish()`.

Comment: Return `false` on your `onTouchuListener` may works, if it stil doesn't work ,then post your `onTouchuListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to easily solve the problem but it's kinda hardcode.

I have set up a touch listener instead of a click listener, then I get the current milliseconds when my finger touch down. When my finger is up, I get the current milliseconds again. So I compare both time, if endTime - startTime < 100 (0.1 seconds), the activity will close. Otherwise it will be consider as a pinch action (Since you can't pinch under 0.1 seconds right?)

Here is my code:

```
   private View.OnTouchListener mAttachmentViewOnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener(){
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              return true;
          }

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              if (endTime - startTime < 100)
                  finish();
              return true;
          }

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
          {
              startTime = 0;
              endTime = 1000;
              return true;
          }
          if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
          {
              startTime = 0;
              endTime = 1000;
              return true;
          }



          return false;
      }
    };
```